# How to change colour of a box div (HTML)

Tags: html

I am trying to create a website and I am separating my information into boxes. I am trying to change the colour of each individual box but it is not working.
Here is my code. The   and  is trying to change the colour of the div.

Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Blank</title>



***<!--Box-->
    <style>.boxed {
      border: 1px solid black ;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        padding-left: 20px;
            padding-right: 20px;
    }
        </style>***


    </head>

    <body>
    <main>
    </main>



    <font face="caslon">  
     <color background: green>
    <div class="boxed"> 
      <h1> <font face="caslon", style="font-weight:bold">How is electricity produced?</font></h1>
    <p style="font-weight:normal">There are multiple ways electricity can be produced that thave been found over the course of history. They differ in their efficency and cost.</p>
    <p style="font-weight:normal">They include: </p>
    </div>
    </color>


    <color background: red>
    <div class="boxed">
        <h3><p style="font-weight:bold">Static electricity</p></h3>
        <p style="font-weight:normal">
    Static electricity is produced by bringing two different materials into contact. This causes a phenomenon known as triboelectricity (or the triboelectric effect). All materials are made of atoms with a positive nucleus and negative electrons orbiting. Some atoms have a stronger pull on these electrons than others. When we bring the two materials into contact one may have a stronger pull on the electrons. When we separate them, electrons can stick to the material with a stronger pull. This results in a material with more electrons and results in static electricity.
    </p>
    </div>
    </color>

    </font>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you even tried to google it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style each `div` with a `background-color`

Try adding this `style="background-color:YourColorCode;"` to your `div`.

For better understanding on `font-face`, see this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

See below snippet:

```css
.boxed {
      border: 1px solid black ;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-right: 50px;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <main>
      </main>
      <div class="boxed" style="background-color:green;"> 
       <h1><font style="font-weight:bold">How is electricity produced?</font></h1>
    <p style="font-weight:normal">There are multiple ways electricity can be produced that thave been found over the course of history. They differ in their efficency and cost.</p>
    <p style="font-weight:normal">They include: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="boxed" style="background-color:red">
        <h3><p style="font-weight:bold">Static electricity</p></h3>
        <p style="font-weight:normal">
    Static electricity is produced by bringing two different materials into contact. This causes a phenomenon known as triboelectricity (or the triboelectric effect). All materials are made of atoms with a positive nucleus and negative electrons orbiting. Some atoms have a stronger pull on these electrons than others. When we bring the two materials into contact one may have a stronger pull on the electrons. When we separate them, electrons can stick to the material with a stronger pull. This results in a material with more electrons and results in static electricity.
    </p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each element an `id`

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3"></div>
```

Your Css will then look like

```
#box1{
    background-color:red;
}
#box2{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

hope it is helpfull to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating custom color tag instead of this use style attribute in div tag.

```
<div class="boxed" style="background-color:green"> 
</div>
```